# Js file is not complete

Tags: javascript, nginx

common.js :

```
//test
function formatChange (change) {
return change > 0 ? '+' + change : change;
}
```

Through the nginx server access to common.js.

```
function formatChange (change) {
return change > 0 ? '+' + change : change;
}�������������
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the encoding of your file to `UTF-8`, it might help.

Comment: try to remove the last line as well and type the curly barcket back but just right after u have utf-8 encoded file.

Comment: I changed the configuration of nginx。sendfile=off